# How to escape a string in Yii 2 formatter component?

Tags: yii2

I have the following configuration for the `formatter` component in my project:

```
'formatter' => [
    'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
    'datetimeFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
    'decimalSeparator' => '.',
    'thousandSeparator' => ' ',
    'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
],
```

Now, for my `datetimeFormat` I'd like to suffix it with an `h` letter/string at the end of it.

I have tried with:

```
'datetimeFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm\\h',
```

But the escaped `\\h` returns a letter `g` there. I know that `\\h` works with `date`.

How do we do escapes with Yii 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it while reading [formatter documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#$datetimeFormat-detail) and [ICU manual](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax).

To achieve this, escape the letter with wrapping your letter/string with single quotes:

```
'datetimeFormat' => "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'h'",
```

Sample output: `30.12.1990 12:25h`.